# Poner Android en standby por programa

Tags: android

Quiero que la aplicación pase el dispositivo a standby como al pulsar la tecla de encender/apagar, pero no encuentro cómo hacerlo.

Answer (score 2):

Esto no lo puede realizar cualquier aplicación, debe ser una aplicación de sistema para que tenga acceso a poder realizar la acción de enviar a Standby el dispositivo.

Para esto puedes hacer uso de la clase [PowerManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#goToSleep%28long%29) pero para esto necesitas el permiso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER"/>
```

que solo es permitido para aplicaciones de sistema.

Con este método lograrías lo que deseas:

```
   private  void toStandBy(){

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "Standby");
        wl.acquire();
        wl.release();
    }
```